# Pull a specific key from an array objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

in PHP when using an array you can use myArray['firstElement'] to pull that specific key and its associated values from the array. How do I do this similar type of thing in objective c?

Comment: When you say 'array', do you mean a primitive array like `int[]`, an ordered collection like `NSArray`, or an associative collection like `NSDictionary`?

Comment: an NSArray but I solved my problem. By using
[myArray objectForKey:@"firstElement"]; it returns that specific segment. thanks

Comment: If you're new to Obj-C, please read the guide [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to deal with key-value pairs, you would use an [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Although it is surprising to note that [`arrays in PHP are an ordered map`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: To access the key use [dict valueForKey:@"key"]

Answer (score 1):

You want to use NSDictionary instead of NSArray.  NSDictionary is an associative array.